# Magento 2: Runtime Exeception

Tags: magento2, error, exception, runtime

I'm getting below kind of Exception

`exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The path "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php.10248" cannot be renamed into "D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php" Warning!rename(D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php.10248,D:/wamp/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32)' in D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Swatche...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Swatche...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Swatche...') #3 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php(38): class_exists('Magento\\Swatche...') #4 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(153): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has('Magento\\Swatche...') #5 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(176): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception('Magento\\Swatche...') #6 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(127): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins('Magento\\Swatche...') #7 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->initialize(Array) #8 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime), Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime), 'interception') #9 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #10 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #11 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #12 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array) #13 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(385): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #14 D:\wamp\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(232): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->initObjectManager() #15 D:\wamp\www\magento2\index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') #16 {main}`

When i refresh page again it works fine. What will be cause of this Exception?

Comment: faced same issue, reload the page then it worked fine.